# perl tiny program, bytecode minimal distro

Tags: perl, deployment, bytecode

Let's say I have a basic program, working only with files and tcp sockets, using select(). No framework, no threading, just basic I/O close to operating system calls. It is a single source file.

Let's see this as a proof of concept.

*I don't have to fight hackers and reverse engineering.*

- Is there a way to build one .plc, that includes also some basic .pm ( files and sockets support ) ?
- On the users' pc, which is the minimal perl runtime install to support this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -MModule::Compile -c foo.pl
perl -MModule::Compile -c Foo.pm
```

… creates plc and pmc files each. Perl automatically checks for pmc files before pm files, but plc files need to be called explicitely. This means it is better to turn your program into a module or modulino.

Runtime requirements are Perl 5.6 and the module Filter::Util::Call, which is in the core since 5.7.3.